# WebActivator PreApplicationStartMethod not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onion-architecture, webactivator

I'm making a new project following onin architecture.

[image]

I have a separate project called "bootstrapper" that contain IOC and WebActivator.. My problem is that class that contain WebActivator not even loaded in debug ! May be i'm missing something ?

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), "RegisterDependencies")]
 public class IocConfig
 {
        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            //..........
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Onion.Bootstrapper` project corresponds to the outermost layer of your Onion Architecture. It's the only projects that references all the others.

Using `WebActivator` allows you to avoid having to reference `Onion.Bootstrapper` in `WebApplication`. The `RegisterDependencies` method will be called on pre-application start.

To make this works, the only thing you need to do is to make sure the `Onion.Bootstrapper` dll is pushed to `WebApplication` **/bin** directory ( (easy to set up using a post build action or *OutputTo* nugget package)).

Comment: @MacSC it is not working for me bro

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking Auto-generate binding redirects on Project > Properties > Application.